# Retrieve data from other model sequelize in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two model in sequelize one is announcements and other is classes. I define relation between them in announcements model.

`announcements.belongsTo(models.classes, { foreignKey: 'classId' });`

how i can fetch the list of all announcements where user enrolled in classes. I have added a `userId` in announcements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to first set the relationship up both ways. It sounds like announcements belongs to classes, and a class can have many announcements, is that correct? In that case, you need to do this:

```
announcements.belongsTo(models.classes, {foreignKey: 'classId'});
classes.hasMany(models.announcements, { as: 'announcements' });
```

From there, you can query it like this:

```
classes.findAll(
      { include: [ {model: models.announcements, as: 'announcements'} ]
)
```

Or whatever your query might be. It's all outlined in their associations documentation: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html